# Get Mime type from file extension

Tags: c, gtk, gnome

Am trying to get Mime type from extension like `.html` should give back `text/html`.
I know how to get Mime with file available but not other way. Is there a way to query mime from extension, at least known ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to use `GContentType` inside GIO:

https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GContentType.html

and to be precise `g_content_type_guess()`:

https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GContentType.html#g-content-type-guess

which takes either a file name, or the file contents, and returns the guessed content type; from there, you can use `g_content_type_get_mime_type()` to get the MIME type for the content type.

this is an example for how to use `g_content_type_guess()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const char *file_name = "test.html";
  gboolean is_certain = FALSE;

  char *content_type = g_content_type_guess (file_name, NULL, 0, &is_certain);

  if (content_type != NULL)
    {
      char *mime_type = g_content_type_get_mime_type (content_type);

      g_print ("Content type for file '%s': %s (certain: %s)\n"
               "MIME type for content type: %s\n",
               file_name,
               content_type,
               is_certain ? "yes" : "no",
               mime_type);

      g_free (mime_type);
    }

  g_free (content_type);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

once compiled, the output on Linux is:

```
Content type for file 'test.html': text/html (certain: no)
MIME type for content type: text/html
```

*explanation*: on Linux, content type is a MIME type; this is not true on other platforms, that's why you must convert `GContentType` strings to MIME type.

also, as you can see, just using the extension will set the boolean *is certain* flag, as an extension by itself is not enough to determine the accurate content type.

Comment: that will require file to be present right? I know what am asking is not that common but I wanted to know mime types for known file types. I could parse /etc/mime.types but I would rather use library that does so. Thanks for great example.

Comment: no, it does not require the file to be present: you just need its name. also, /etc/mime.types is completely pointless on any modern Linux: you want the shared-mime-info database, which is part of freedesktop.org: http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/shared-mime-info/

Comment: so I can put any dummy name like dummy.html? Thats what I need. I will accept it for now!

Comment: Thanks ebassi for his nice and clean answer.
I encountered some liking errors during testing this code, so I decided to share the command I used to compile it:
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs dbus-glib-1 dbus-1 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0 gio-2.0` test.c